# Can I make hostile mobs/nether mobs "hatch" from eggs in Creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft 1.1 there's been the addition of eggs. Everything can now be "hatched" (including Villagers...) I've started a new (flat) map to have a play around with epic creeper battles but can't get hostile or nether-based mobs to spawn. The "Enderman" egg results in the purple particles showing, and the ghast egg produces a ghast scream. I thought about they can't survive in the sun so I built a little shelter for them...still no luck. I tried digging a hole far down to see if I could get a slime to spawn but didn't realise the shallow depth of an ultra-flat map and fell out to my death.

How do I get the evil beasties?

Comment: I don't know what could be your problem, Yogscast got it working: [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbghsTyIbO0&t=3m20s). Is your .minecraft folder clean?

Comment: Is this a multiplayer server?

Comment: @MyFaJoArCo, no mods installed, only two previous saved games and a couple of screenshots - and it's Creative Single Player

Comment: For the record, slimes spawn on the surface in the ultra-flat maps. They're a major hazard in survival mode.

Comment: @Random832, yeah, I've already expereinced that. Why would you do survivial on ultra-flat though?!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm having no trouble doing this in single player:

[image: mobs spawned from eggs]

What's your difficulty? If it's peaceful, then all mobs will despawn instantly.

Comment: Oh, difficulty, of course!

Comment: Difficulty. That was it. <sighface> that'll teach me to play on peaceful all the time.

Answer (score 4):

You have to remember the difficulty cannot be peaceful, once you switch it to anything but peaceful, it will work fine.